Whether error will throw if we use null date in DATEDIFF() in MYSQL
I have a query to be run in one IAM tool where we are comparing last passwordchangedate and now.
i just needs to know whether below query will throw error if we pass null value inside DATEDIFF()?
SELECT DISTINCT 
u.username AS UName,
u.statuskey AS SK,
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), u.createdate) >= 30 
         AND DATEDIFF(Now(),a.LASTPASSWORDCHANGE) <= 30 
         AND u.customproperty18 !='Y' 
         AND u.customproperty63 IS NULL THEN 'Inactive'
    ELSE u.customproperty17
END AS CP17
FROM 
users u
WHERE
  ((DATEDIFF(Now(),u.createdate) > 30 
   AND DATEDIFF(Now(),a.LASTPASSWORDCHANGE) <= 30 

i just needs to know what will happen if we pass null in DATEDIFF and what is solution for this.
what i needs to modify in my above query

Hi - what’s stopping you from trying this to see what happens?


i just needs to know whether below query will throw error if we pass null value inside DATEDIFF()?

No. The documentation explicitly tells that

DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
...
This function returns NULL if expr1 or expr2 is NULL.

So the case when the argument value is NULL is a regular feature and not an error. Neither an error nor a warning is generated. And your progran won't receive any signal that it'd throw an exception.

Use a wrapper of condition statement for NULL Date validation as follows:
SELECT DISTINCT 
u.username AS UName,
u.statuskey AS SK,
CASE 
  WHEN(u.createdate is not NULL AND a.LASTPASSWORDCHANGE is not NULL)  THEN 
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), u.createdate) >= 30 
            AND DATEDIFF(Now(),a.LASTPASSWORDCHANGE) <= 30 
            AND u.customproperty18 !='Y' 
            AND u.customproperty63 IS NULL THEN 'Inactive'
        ELSE u.customproperty17
    END 
END AS CP17
FROM 
users u
WHERE (
  (u.createdate is not NULL AND a.LASTPASSWORDCHANGE is not NULL)
  AND DATEDIFF(Now(),u.createdate) > 30 
  AND DATEDIFF(Now(),a.LASTPASSWORDCHANGE) <= 30 
)

I think it should work.
Thank you
